# Center Logo Text In NavBar, HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I am having a problem in my **NAVBAR** code!

Everything in my **HTML** and **CSS** is **set up correctly**, I am having the **problem** in **one specific line** of code where I am trying to **Center The Text Logo**!

Or should I **specify another line** of code to **Center my Text Logo**?

I put the **Logo** as a **Text** as **I don't want to have an image as a logo**.

But, now I am trying to **Center** the **Logo Text** in the **Middle** of the **NAVBAR**

but **it is not working**. I don't know how to **put in the middle**!

Please help!

PS: **I don't want to change the current code**, I just want to **Center the Logo Text**.

**This is my Full Code in HTML and CSS!**

Please **Run it on your Editor** to get a **better understanding** of it! Thank you for all your help.

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/0c0d062607.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/style.css" />
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/0c0d062607.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <title>My Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="topnav">
      <a class="active" href="#home"><i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i> Home</a>
      <a href="portfolio.html"><i class="fa-solid fa-wallet"></i> Portfolio</a>
      <a href="contact.html"
        ><i class="fa-regular fa-circle-user"></i> Contact</a
      >
      <a href="about.html"><i class="fa-regular fa-comment"></i> About</a>
      
      <a href="index.html" id="logo">My Logo</a>
      <div class="social">
        <a
          class="facebook"
          href="https://facebook.com"
          target="_blank"
          title="Facebook"
          ><i class="fa-brands fa-facebook"></i>&nbsp Facebook</a
        >
        <a
          class="instagram"
          href="https://instagram.com"
          target="_blank"
          title="Instagram"
          ><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>&nbsp Instagram</a
        >
        <a
          class="twitter"
          href="https://twitter.com"
          target="_blank"
          title="Twitter"
          ><i class="fa-brands fa-twitter"></i>&nbsp Twitter</a
        >
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
    body {
  background-image: url(../images/body_bg.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.topnav {
  background-color: rgb(54, 54, 54);
  overflow: hidden;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  border-top: 3px solid rgb(250, 186, 113);
  border-bottom: 3px solid rgb(250, 186, 113);
  filter: saturate(2);
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", Calibri, "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
  color: rgb(250, 186, 113);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 11px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: rgb(250, 186, 113);
  color: white;
}

.social {
  float: right;
}
```

Comment: Please tag only related to the question. There are nothing related to JS, Windows, Bootstrap 4.

Comment: I am sorry...I am new to StackOverflow and i thought to put what is related to Html and CSS..This is noted :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can do something like that

```
   <a href="index.html" id="logo" style="position: absolute;left: 50%;">My Logo</a>
```

Comment: OMG that worked PERFECTLY FINE! I just implemented the style on CSS and the 'a href' in HTML and worked like butter! Thank you so so much, this was really helpful for future reference. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Try this code. I just changed few things into your code. Only 4-5 lines. Have look hope it will help you and fix your problem.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/0c0d062607.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/0c0d062607.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <title>My Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="topnav">
            <div class="links">
                <a class="active" href="#home"><i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i> Home</a>
                <a href="portfolio.html"><i class="fa-solid fa-wallet"></i> Portfolio</a>
                <a href="contact.html"><i class="fa-regular fa-circle-user"></i> Contact</a>
                <a href="about.html"><i class="fa-regular fa-comment"></i> About</a>
            </div>
        
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="index.html" id="logo">My Logo</a>
            </div>

            <div class="social">
                <a class="facebook" href="https://facebook.com" target="_blank" title="Facebook"><i class="fa-brands fa-facebook"></i>&nbsp Facebook</a>
                <a class="instagram" href="https://instagram.com" target="_blank" title="Instagram"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>&nbsp Instagram</a>
                <a class="twitter" href="https://twitter.com" target="_blank" title="Twitter"><i class="fa-brands fa-twitter"></i>&nbsp Twitter</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
    body {
    background-image: url(../images/body_bg.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  }
  
  .topnav {
    background-color: rgb(54, 54, 54);
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    border-top: 3px solid rgb(250, 186, 113);
    border-bottom: 3px solid rgb(250, 186, 113);
    filter: saturate(2);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  
  .topnav a {
    float: left;
    font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", Calibri, "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
    color: rgb(250, 186, 113);
    text-align: center;
    padding: 11px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  
  .topnav a:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  }
  
  .topnav a.active {
    background-color: rgb(250, 186, 113);
    color: white;
  }
  
  .social {
    float: right;
  }
```

[Have a look. It's perfect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zIKE.png)

Comment: Thank you so much for this! The one provided above also worked perfectly fine in just one line of code. I just had to do it this way: **<a href="index.html" id="logo" style="position: absolute;left: 50%;">My Logo</a>** // I just implemented the style on CSS and **a href** in HTML and worked really well. Thank you so much guys, you are the best!

Comment: Try to use general coding. The above code in your reply may works too. But I'll suggest you to make your codes clean. So that other also can understand it. And clean way also helps you when you make your site responsive. Hope you got it.

Comment: Thank you so much for the advise! I am trying to do it, but I just started learning HTML and CSS for the first time 3 months ago, and I am still new to it! But thank you :D